# Novelty of finding an application for existing results

Tags: publications, mathematics, publishability

I have just completed work on certain problem that was ignored in applied mathematics but is well developed in pure mathematics for forty years. I mean there are certain formulations that were developed forty years ago but nobody seriously used them in applied mathematics, I have used those formulations and derived very decent results.

I am considering to submit my work to a high-ranking journal for applied mathematics, which mentions novelty in their criteria for submission.
On one hand, I do not consider my work original work as I have just shown application of certain formulations which were ignored by many. On the other hand, when I look at publications in that journal, my work seems to be better.

Can a work that just applies existing results be novel enough to warrant publication in a high-ranking journal?

Comment: What does it say in the journal's instructions to authors?

Comment: @ff524: The journal(Applied Mathematics Letters) use word `novelty`, but as I said I have shown application of certain formulation which was ignore earlier, so I don't think my work is novel one, but when I look at publications in that journal, my work seems to be better one.

Comment: Related answer: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/62913/20058

Comment: I don't believe that we can guess which category your particular paper should be categorized into without knowing quite a lot of details about both the paper and the journal.

Comment: @jakebeal I want to submit my work to applied mathematics letter but afraid of getting rejected as I am not sure of category of my work, but I believe it should be submitted to AML.

Comment: @IgotiT Have you talked with your advisor?  Other colleagues? The journal editor?

Comment: On this problem I am working independently and my advisor don't know about this subject as I am carrying this work just because of personal interest. Should I ask the editor of AML ?

Comment: @IgotiT yeah, ask the editor about your paper, I think that will be faster and more relevant.

Comment: I'm not convinced about this "ask the editor" thing.  If an editor's going to desk-reject a manuscript as out of scope, I'm inclined to think it's better for everyone that they receive a formal submission and desk-reject it through the official, transparent. auditable channels rather than through some pre-submission back door.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous results in theoretical and applied mathematics that remain hidden in a field-specific journal for many years before their general applicability becomes known. Consider, for example, the [most-cited paper in mathematics/computation](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2003354) which builds on work originally developed by Gauss (see, for example, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) on the Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm). Critically, the paper has spawned numerous others showing the applicability and usefulness of the Fast Fourier Transform to a wide range of other domains. Who, for example, would have originally conceived that it might find usefulness in [anaesthesia](https://doi.org/10.1093/bja/45.7.664)!

I think that your self-critical and self-disparaging comments (e.g., "to me, this is not original work") are unjustified. Original work in mathematics can be anything from posing (and not necessarily solving) important problems ([Hilbert's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_problems) being an obvious example, the [Langlands program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program) being another) ... to communicating mathematics to a wider audience. See, for example, the paper, *["What is Good Mathematics",](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702396)* by Terrence Tao.

As to which journal might best be suited to publish your results, I don't know, but don't mislead yourself into believing that "original work" is all of one kind.